# Running Docker in PyCharm using Windows and virtualenv (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, windows, docker, tensorflow, pycharm

I am trying to run Docker in my PyCharm project. My PyCharm project uses Python 2.7, whereas the system default Python is 3.4. I installed Docker through [this](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/) tutorial. I start the Docker engine using in my virtual env of Python 2.7:

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`

I can access it through my browser using `http://192.168.99.101:8888` and it executes Python 2.7 code.

Now I want to use Docker in my existing PyCharm 2.7 project. (note that I use Anaconda and that I use plenty of packages which I would like to keep).

Is there any way to run the Tensorflow Docker Image in my PyCharm project? (any other solution to run Tensorflow in PyCharm is fine as well).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can tell PyCharm to use a interpreter inside a docker container. This, however, only works with PyCharm Professional.

First, go to **Preferences -> Project Interpreter** (under Project: ...) and click on the gear  or dots to the right of Project Interpreter near the top. In the **Configure Remote Python Interpreter** dialog, click the Docker button.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/#make-pycharm-docker-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/docker-2.html), particularly API section for api url.
Below settings work fine for windows10.

Note: works only with **Professional Edition**

[image]